# Centering a tags in my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

So I've been having a pretty simple problem regarding a navigation bar with HTML and CSS. Im trying to center my a tags + logo +  inside my navigation bar, but no matter what I do I just cant seem to make it happen without adding line-height:x pixels; to every seperate tag, but even then some dont work as intended. I've tried using text-align:center; in my #menu but it just doesn't seem to work? Sorry if it's a stupid question but I just dont see it..

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type=text/css>
    <script>

        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();

            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);

            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }
        function checkTime(i) {
            if(i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; 
            return i;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <img src="axelhalldin.png">
    <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Hem</a></li>
    <li><a href="game.html">Projekt</a></li>    
    <li><a href="about.html">Om mig</a></li>
    <li><div id="clock"></div></li> 
</ul>
    </nav> 

    <div id="welcome"><center><h2>Välkommen!</h2> <p>Den här sidan är skapad för att visa upp mina projekt inom webbprogrammering, och även lite om mig själv. Använd menyn ovan för att ta dig runt i webbsidan.   </p></center></div> 


    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
}
#menu {
    width:100%;
    height:6.5em;
    background-color:#00334d;
}
footer {
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:3em;
    background-color:#00334d;
    text-align:center;

}
#footerparagraph{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:0.75em;
    margin:0 -85em 0 0;
}
#myCanvas {
    border-style:solid;
    margin:5em 22em;
    box-shadow:0em 0em 1.25em 0.5em;
}
#imageAxel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0.3em;
    border-radius:0.01em;
    border-color:white;
    box-shadow:;
    margin-top:3.75em;
    margin-left:-2.6em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
#clock {
    float:right;
    color:white;
    margin:0em 2em 0em 0em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.75em;
    line-height:3.5em;
}
#about{
    width:20em;
    height:31.25em;
    background-color:#00334d;
    margin: 100px 125px;
    padding:;
}
#aboutText {
    width:40em;
    height:31.25em;
    background-color:#00334d;
    margin:-600px 415px;
    padding:;
}
a {
    font-size:2em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:lightgrey;
    padding:0.25em;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:1em 2em 0px 2em;
}
a.active {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:white;
    color:white:;
}
a:hover{
    color:white;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    color:white;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-style:italic;
}
header {
    background-color:#00334d;
    color:white;
}
li {
display:inline;
}
p {
    color:white; 
    padding:15px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    margin:1.5em 0em;
}
ul {
text-decoration:none;
display:inline;
}
#welcome{
    background-color:#00334d;
    font-family:Verdana;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding:30px;
}
#pAbout{
    max-width:200px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your question @axul! Is this the simplest example you can provide? Minimal examples will help people help you faster...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somthing like this:

```
 #menu img {
     /*--- css for img in menu ---*/
}

 #menu li{
     float:left;  /*--- Make the list go horizontal ---*/
     margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal and vertical centering are separate issues. Adding `text-align: center` to the #menu selector is a perfectly good way to center things horizontally, and it worked for me when I tried it. (At least as far as I could tell without JSBin loading your logo image.)

The reason that your vertical centering was off was the default padding applied to some elements in your ul. You can fix that with the following.

```
ul *{
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

You might consider using a CSS reset to make the margins and paddings of all elements 0 until you deliberately set them otherwise, in order to head this sort of thing off proactively.

Here's the link to my JSBin with the changes.
http://jsbin.com/sukogopixa/edit?html,css,output